# Loading data in to UIPIckerView based on the field that is tapped

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I am trying to find a way to load data into my PickerView when the user taps on the different fields in the view. I had it working early on then as I finished other parts of the view, this is no longer working. The data is hard coded for now to get the functionality of the project in place then the data will be pulled from an XML file generated on our main server containing this users specific data.

Right now I am just trying to get the picker to work for one field (enterDispTo) but eventually the code needs to work for the three non-date fields in the view.

Here is the code I have currently. Sorry it is so long but I did not want to leave out something that may be the issue. This is very new to me.

```
import UIKit
```

class DispenseScreen1ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {

```
// keep your outlets at the top
@IBOutlet var myDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
@IBOutlet var userLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var teamLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var enterDate: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var enterSeason: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var enterSport: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var enterDispTo: UITextField!

// put variables and constants here
let today = NSDate()
var season = traSeason
var sport = traSport
var dispensedToSelector = dispensedTo
var activeField = []
var datePickerView = UIDatePicker()
var fieldDataPickerView = UIPickerView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    userLabel.text = userName
    teamLabel.text = teamName

    // initialize the inputView of the transaction date field to a datePickerView. This will allow the date picker to appear when the field is tapped
    enterDate.inputView = datePickerView

    // this limits the date picker to date only
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
    datePickerView.date = NSDate()
    enterDate.text = NSDate().formatted
    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: "dateChangedAction", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    //initailize the inputView of the season field to the PickerView. This will allow the picker to appear when the field is tapped
    enterSeason.inputView = fieldDataPickerView

    if season.count > 0 {
        enterSeason.text = season[0] as! String //value in [] will be a var that sets default season
    }

    //initailize the inputView of the season field to the PickerView. This will allow the picker to appear when the field is tapped
    enterSport.inputView = fieldDataPickerView

    if sport.count == 1 {

        enterSport.text = sport[0] as String //need to convert to a string
        enterSport.enabled = false //do not allow editing

    } else {
        //do nothing
    }

    //initailize the inputView of the enterDispTo field to the PickerView. This will allow the picker to appear when the field is tapped
    enterDispTo.inputView = fieldDataPickerView

    enterDispTo.text = dispensedToSelector[0]

}

func dateChangedAction() {
    datePickerView.maximumDate = NSDate()
    enterDate.text = datePickerView.date.formatted
}

//func fieldChangedAction() {
   // enterDispTo.text = self.itemSelected
//}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//load data into PickerView and return the value selected
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
    }
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return self.activeField.count
    }
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return self.activeField[row] as! String
    }
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    var itemSelected = self.activeField[row] as! String
    }

//function to hide keyboard when return key is tapped
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

//funtion to hide keyboard when screen is tapped
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@IBAction func seasonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    //code for what to do when season field is tapped
    activeField = season
}


@IBAction func sportTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    //code for what to do when sport field is tapped
    activeField = sport
}


@IBAction func dispToTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    //code for what to do when dispTo is tapped
    activeField = dispensedToSelector
    //fieldDataPickerView.addTarget(self, action: "fieldChangedAction", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
}
```

}
`extension NSDate {
    var formatted: String {
        let df = NSDateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
        df.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_us_POSIX")
        return df.stringFromDate(self)
    }
}`

Comment: You have a debugger. Debug! Figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: @matt I am happy to use the debugger. Next question. I have located the debug navigator and I am now more confused than ever. Is there some reference I can go to on how to use the debugger? Keeping in mind, this is my first project ever and I didn't even know there was a  debugger.

Comment: My book might help you. What you want to do is pause at a breakpoint at the start of a method and step through, watching your variables to see if their values are making sense. http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch09.html#_debugging

Comment: @matt Thank you. I will take a look at your book. I have actually bookmarked it but I did not see anything specific to debugging. I may have missed it.

Comment: @matt I have looked at the section from your book on debugging. Thanks for that. I have tried many different breakpoints and walked through code step by step. My challenge at this point is I am not sure what the information is telling me. My variables are what I expect them to be but still my pickerView is blank. I have tried using the playground but that has been even less productive.  Right now, my issue is that when I tap on a field, a pickerView appears at the bottom of the screen with no data in it. My currentField variable is correct and the data for the variable is correct.  Help!